# Passing null in putExtra in Android Intent giving compile time error?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use `putExtra(String,String)` in my code to pass `null`.
As the parameter suggests the second parameter can be `null` as it is a string and I can send it

```
this.getIntent().putExtra(AppConstant.TestString, null);
```

When i use the above code it gives me error saying :

**The method putExtra(String, String) is ambiguous for the type Intent**

However it allows me to use :

```
this.getIntent().putExtra(AppConstant.TestString, "");
```

Kindly enlighten me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you use `null`, the compiler doesn't know which is the type you want to use and cannot decide which overload of the method to use.

You can cast your null to `String` to inform compiler which method you use:

```
this.getIntent().putExtra(AppConstant.TestString, (String)null);
```

Alternatively, you can create a variable and set it to `null`:

```
String param = null;
this.getIntent().putExtra(AppConstant.TestString, param);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as the second parameter is null it can't tell which method you want to call: `putExtra(String name, float value)`, `putExtra (String name, byte[] value)`, `putExtra (String name, long[] value)`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Android can not determine what you are passing (`String`,`boolean`,`int`) when you use

`this.getIntent().putExtra(AppConstant.TestString, null);`

but when you use

`this.getIntent().putExtra(AppConstant.TestString, "");`

it knows that you are passing it as a `String`

Comment: I know it's late to say but `boolean` is by default `false` and `int` is 0 in Java, not null. Right?

Comment: Yes but when you use `null` it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Use intent.removeExtra(extraName) instead. It clears the extra and is more clean than using typecasting in putExtra.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html